# List posts in a given category

Tags: posts, wp-query, categories

I am using this code to get all posts sorted alphabetically in a given category, it works, but I feel the code can be improved...

```
<?php
$cats = get_categories('include=5');
foreach ($cats as $cat) {
    echo "<ul>";
    $args        = array(
        'cat' => 5,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
    $custom_loop = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($custom_loop->have_posts()) {
        $custom_loop->the_post();
        $category = get_the_category();
        // Only display a post link once, even if it's in multiple categories
        if ($category[0]->cat_ID == $cat->cat_ID) {
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
wp_reset_query();
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

You are already passing category in `$args`. so not need to use `get_categories()`. You can use below code.

```
   $args = array(
        'cat' => 5,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
    $custom_loop = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($custom_loop->have_posts()) {
       echo "<ul>";
        while ($custom_loop->have_posts()) {
            $custom_loop->the_post();
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
        }
       echo "</ul>";
   }
   wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: It worked, thanks!